# weird output in Pool.map_async

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

this is my code (i know it makes no sense):

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


def mult(n):
    for i in range(n):
        n-=1
        print(n)

listed=[t for t in range(5000)]
if __name__=='__main__':
    begin1=time.time()
    x=map(mult,listed)
    x=list(x)
    print(x[50])
    print(time.time()-begin1)
    begin2=time.time()
    p=mp.Pool(8).map_async(mult,listed).get()
    print(p)
    print(time.time()-begin2)
```

the point of this code was to understand the Pools compared to the map function since it's not faster for me...
anyway when i run this code the Pools section shows weird numbers.
if somebody knows the reason i would like to hear it :)
thank you!!

Comment: Just a note: the "it's not faster for me" is almost certainly due to you starting 8 processes to do a trivial subtraction job. The overhead of the process creation surely dwarfs the job time.

Comment: Thanks :) do you know about the weird numbers?

Comment: You'd need to clarify what you mean by "weird numbers", but it could be due to the print calls from multiple processes being interleaved, causing the newlines to be "misplaced", and different printouts to "smear together". If the spacing of what's printed is also wonky, that's probably it. To solve that, you'll need to learn about thread/process synchronization. `multiprocessing.Lock` is your friend here.

Comment: I think ithis is probaly the answer :) thank you!!

Comment: You can also try adding `flush=True` to your print statements so you get a single output on a single line. But with multiprocessing, whether you do the printing under control of  a lock or not, you cannot be sure of the order in which the print statements will be executed by the worker function (`mult` in this case) since you do not have fine control over the dispatching of the pool processes.

Comment: The order doesnt matter :) the code i try to make does many sql queries so i don't want it to wait for the answer on every single query. This is why the multiprocess is the answer i'm probaly looking for :)